# Support Landscape and Portrait Orientation for ios 5 (storyboard)

Tags: iphone, xcode, orientation, storyboard

How can I support portrait and landscape orientation for Tab bar application in ios 5 (StoryBoard).

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: In storyboard also we have autoresizing facility same as XIB.

Answer (score 1):

UITabBarController have a some problem. the problems is a subviews(selected index) not autorotate.

So, you can make a category, and add a below code.

and, add a #import "UITabBarController+Autorotate.h"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface UITabBarController (Autorotate)

@end
```

---

```
#import "UITabBarController+Autorotate.h"


@implementation UITabBarController (Autorotate)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    UIViewController *controller = self.selectedViewController;
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        controller = [(UINavigationController *)controller visibleViewController];
    return [controller shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

@end
```